# Choice of IPC method in distributed system

Tags: c#, c, wcf, ipc, distributed-system

We build software that is Multi layer and every layer can implement in different platform. For example one of our applications in interface layer is C# and silverlight in windows and other application in Engine layer is C in linux. Applications in Engine have relation to other layer and database, so applications in interface layer access to DB and other layer via Engine layer. For example Engine receive request from interface and connect to DB and send query to it and receive the answer and send it to interface. Which method is suitable to communication between interface applications and Engine applications?
(RPC or  Socket)?
can we use WCF?

Answer (score 1):

You can use WCF on the .Net (C#) parts but other platforms will not easily be able to talk with it, with an exception - you can expose WCF as a REST endpoint which I have had pretty good success using with inter-platform communications. But if your going to do that you might consider not using WCF in favor of the .Net Web.API which is built around REST.

Another thing you can do is create a common component just for communications, a message broker of sorts:

Assuming each letter is a different platform here is your problem:

A -> B

B -> C

C -> A

Create a new component that handles communications with a standard way of communicating (like REST) that each platform can use:

A -> Broker -> B

B -> Broker -> C

C -> Broker -> A

HTH,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are the ubiquitous mechanism, so in case of cross-platform and cross-language application they are probably the most natural choice. WCF would not be an option if you need to involve something non-Windows in future (such as iOS mobiles).

To avoid reinventing the wheel, you need to use some message-oriented middleware (MOM), which fits nicely to your scheme. There exist several such products on the market, both open-source and commercial. Most of such products support only one or two major platforms, though.

Our company created a middleware product, which is available for free with source code, [MsgConnect](https://www.eldos.com/msgconnect/). This product addresses problems like yours. It's available on the number of platforms (silverlight is not supported though, due to very limited socket architecture in Silverlight) and offers several alternative transports including TCP sockets, UDP and memory-mapped files for efficient local communications.